# BLOB type image can't fetched from mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

This is my code for uploading image to `mysql` `database` using `android`.

```
Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, data);
```

I compressed it before uploading

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
return encodedImage;
```

It works perfectly fine and it uploading image into the `db` also.
This is my `php` code for fetching the image into the web dashboard.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'" width="50px" height="50px"/>';?>
```

But the above code not displaying the image only displaying the alter msg.
But when i insert image into the `mysql` db using `phpmyadmin` it displaying in the web dashboard. I can't understand what happening. Please help me

Comment: Post php code too hard to tell just by client side code.

Answer (score 0):

I think because it's already encoded, u have send it in base64 , so try to remove base64_encode from the img tag because u are encoding it twice.